# How do I add Swagger to an existing Node app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, swagger-node-express

The documentation for Swagger (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node) only shows how to create a new app. How do I integrate Swagger into an existing API app?

Comment: Are you trying to integrate the swagger-api library (which is a framework built on top of express that handles routing) in your existing project, or do you just want to add swagger documentation files?

Comment: I want to both integrate the Swagger API library and created Swagger documentation files.

Answer (score 2):

I followed this guide: https://blog.cloudboost.io/adding-swagger-to-existing-node-js-project-92a6624b855b

```
npm i swagger-ui-express -S
```

I used the Swagger editor to create a `swagger.yml` file. http://editor.swagger.io/

I added this to my server:

```
var swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express')
var fs = require('fs')
var jsyaml = require('js-yaml');
var spec = fs.readFileSync('swagger.yml', 'utf8');
var swaggerDocument = jsyaml.safeLoad(spec);
...
app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));
```

I was then able to access Swagger docs via `http://localhost/api-docs`.

It's unfortunately not the same level of integration that Swagger has with Spring Boot in Java, where you can add an annotation and Swagger will automatically generate the documentation for you. It seems Swagger for Node requires you to maintain the `swagger.yml` documentation manually.  I have my routes defined like `app.use('/users', userRouter)` and inside the `users.js` file I have functions defined like `router.post('/status', (req, res) => { ... }`. That doesn't seem compatible with Swagger for Node, which has a concept of `operationId` which somehow points to a function name.